# Bluetooth not working and always disabled. What is the problem?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers

My bluetooth of Dell Inspiron 3521 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is always turned off and never working.

[image: see this image]

Output of `rfkill list` is:

```
phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

The output for `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` is surprisingly too long, but the

starting lines are:

```
[   13.604878] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   13.604893] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.604897] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.604899] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.604903] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.255339] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   24.251910] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   24.260749] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   24.276755] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   24.276761] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   24.435842] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   24.435879] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   29.649634] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.649640] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.649645] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  807.637085] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[  815.628818] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[  815.636981] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  815.652959] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[  815.652974] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[  815.653017] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[  815.653023] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
```